# Keep SKNodes from applying force to each other

Tags: ios, macos, sprite-kit, game-physics

I have two `SKNode` objects. Their positions change when they collide.

How can I prevent that? At the same time, I still want to be able to respond to them contacting via `- (void)didBeginContact`;

I tried setting both their `mass` property to `0.0f` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by setting category, collision and contact bit masks.

```
uint32_t bodyABitMask = 1<<0;
uint32_t bodyBBitMask = 1<<1;

//A mask that defines which categories this physics body belongs to.
[bodyA setCategoryBitMask:bodyABitMask];
[bodyB setCategoryBitMask:bodyBBitMask];

//A mask that defines which categories of physics bodies 
//can collide with this physics body.
[bodyA setCollisionBitMask:0];
[bodyB setCollisionBitMask:0];

//A mask that defines which categories of bodies cause 
//intersection notifications with this physics body.
[bodyA setContactTestBitMask:bodyBBitMask];
[bodyB setContactTestBitMask:bodyABitMask];
```

In above case bodyA and bodyB cannot collide, but you will receive didBeginContact once they are in contact.

Comment: Awesome! I was looking for the `collisionBitMask` property. Thank you!